# SAGA GIS - regression kriging

Tags: qgis, interpolation, saga, kriging

I have a problem with regression kriging in SAGA under QGIS. It gives me an error - could not execute the tool. I want to create temperature maps from data set of meteorologic station and DEM.

I have QGIS 3.30.0 and SAGA GIS 7.8.2. I use tool -> Raster creation tools -> Regression kriging.

To the parameter points I add feature with meteorologic station (teplota_stanice) where the attribute is temperature (T17brezen or T17duben and so on). And in to parametr predictors I add feature GRID of DEM (DMR5g - DEM for Czech Republic). And I leave the other settings as recommended.

There is an error:

```
 ____________________________     
 SAGA Version: 7.8.2 (64 bit)
 ____________________________
 library path: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\saga\tools\
 library name: statistics_kriging
 library : statistics_kriging
 tool : Regression Kriging
 identifier : 3
 author : O.Conrad (c) 2015
 processors : 4 [4]
 ____________________________
 
 Load shapes: D:/school/mgr/diplomka/data_meteo/teplota_stanice.shp...
 
 Loading grid: C:/Users/lucih/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_sAyKSf/566dd01d872648e9b7ad3909798f4aa4/dmrrastrlai.sgrd...     
 
 Parameters     
 
 Grid System: 20; 879x 1448y; 630210x 5433370y
 Points: teplota_stanice
 Attribute: T17brezen
 Predictors: 1 object (dmrrastrlai)
 Regression:
 Prediction:
 Residuals:
 Prediction Error:
 Error Measure: standard deviation
 Regression: Coefficients:
 Regression: Model:
 Regression: Steps:
 Include X Coordinate: false
 Include Y Coordinate: false
 Intercept: true
 Method: stepwise
 Significance Level: 5.000000
 Resampling: B-Spline Interpolation
 Maximum Distance: 0.000000
 Lag Distance Classes: 100
 Skip: 1
 Variogram Model: a + b * x
 Kriging Type: Simple Kriging
 Logarithmic Transformation: false
 Block Kriging: false
 Block Size: 100.000000
 Search Range: global
 Number of Points: all points within search distance
 
 Multiple Regression Analysis (Points and Predictor Grids)
 
 Parameters     
 
 Grid System: 20; 879x 1448y; 630210x 5433370y
 Predictors: 1 object (dmrrastrlai)
 Points: teplota_stanice
 Dependent Variable: T17brezen
 Details: Coefficients: Regression: Coefficients
 Details: Model: Regression: Model
 Details: Steps: Regression: Steps
 Residuals:
 Regression: Regression
 Regression with Residual Correction: 
 Resampling: B-Spline Interpolation
 Include X Coordinate: false
 Include Y Coordinate: false
 Intercept: true
 Method: stepwise
 Significance Level: 5.000000
 Cross Validation: none    
 
 Error: could not execute tool [statistics_regression].[Multiple Regression Analysis (Points and Predictor Grids)]
 Error: executing tool [Regression Kriging]
```

There is a link to download the dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PoGXjPKf2gtVf_sGm8WwrrTG9KINGWA-/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. In order to help you, we need you to [Edit] the Question to contain a lot more information. What exact release of QGIS are you using? What exact tool are you using? What parameters have you provided? ...

Comment: @Vince Thank you for your interest. I edited the question and I hope it will be enough.

Comment: Please place the error message in the body of the Question as text. Images are not legible on all devices, and can't be searched by others (which is the point here).

Comment: @Vince I'm very sorry, I hope everything will be alright now.

Comment: Can you share a small sample of your dataset?

Comment: @Nikos I added information about the dataset and I hope it is what you meant.

Comment: No, I meant to actually share them by providing a link to download them.

Comment: @Nikos Oh, I am so sorry.  I hope everything will be alright now.

Comment: I think there is an issue with your data. The points and the raster layer you provided, although they seem to have the same CRS, their extents don't seem to match (at all!). I don't know if I can post an image here on the comments section to illustrate the problem. Could you please edit your question and show using a print screen, if your shp and raster have similar extents?

Comment: @Nikos I have a DEM defined for the area of ​​my future analysis. And the meteorological stations are from a different area. And I need to create an interpolation temperature map for an area like DEM.

And I only have values ​​from the listed meteorological stations (in print screen).